# Unity 9-slice in multiple sprite sheet

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite-sheet

I have problems 9-slicing my sprites in a spritesheet in Unity 5.2.
Unity seems to ignore the 9-slice even though I've set the borders correctly. My button graphics becomes all stretched out, here is the spritesheet with the borders set on the buttons.

[image]

If I try to do the same slicing on a single sprite file then it works.

[image]

Is it not possible to 9-slice in a spritesheet? Or am I doing something wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done it is by using a script to copy over all the sprite info into the multi-texture spritesheet:

```
int numberOfItemSlices = rects.Count(); //total number of sprites

List<SpriteMetaData> mapSlices = new List<SpriteMetaData>();

for (int sliceCounter=0; sliceCounter<numberOfItemSlices; sliceCounter++) {
   SpriteMetaData mapSlice0 = new SpriteMetaData();
   mapSlice0.name = textureNames[sliceCounter];
   mapSlice0.rect = rects[sliceCounter];

   if (sprites[sliceCounter] != null && sprites[sliceCounter].border != null) {
     mapSlice0.border = sprites[sliceCounter].border;
   }

   mapSlices.Add(mapSlice0);
}

importer.spritesheet = mapSlices.ToArray();
```

**sprites**: array of sprites which you can `AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<Sprite>()` on your source sprites.

**importer**: texture importer for your new atlas

**textureNames**: If you want, you can also name your sprites in the multi-sprite texture.